# Getting justify-content: stretch to have an effect

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Why doesn't `justify-content: stretch;` increase the width of the cells here so that the ends of the first and last cell touch the ends of the container's content-area (as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/))?

It would be great to have a demonstration of how `stretch` can alter the grid-items here (that is, makes them appear different to `justify-content: start;`.

```css
#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 200px;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

#grid-container > div:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    margin: 8px;
}

#grid-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-align):

> Note that certain values of justify-content and align-content can cause **the tracks** to be **spaced apart** (space-around, space-between, space-evenly) or **to be resized** (stretch).

The "*to be resized*" is the key you are missing here. If you specify an explicit size then there is no room for resizing because `justify-content` cannot change the track size explicitely defined .

Use an auto size and you will clearly see the effect:

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
}

#grid-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 8px;
}

#grid-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-container" style="justify-content:start">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-container" style="justify-content:space-around">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-container" style="justify-content:space-between">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>
</div>
```

The other trick is that the default value is already `stretch` which create another confusing because you will think it's doing nothing when it's already applying:

> Initial:   normal <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-content)</sup>

Then you can read

> normal Behavior  |  normal behaves as stretch. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#distribution-grid)</sup>

---

You can also read:

> By default, grid items stretch to fill their grid area. However, if justify-self or align-self compute to a value other than stretch or margins are auto, grid items will auto-size to fit their contents. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#alignment)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you have to use `display: grid` ?

For what you've described, `display: flex` seems to suit your needs better.

You can use this, alongside `flex-direction: column`, to achieve a row by row div, where each div takes up the maximum space it can.

In the example I've provided, only the margins you have set are preventing the div's from having a full width. You can remove these if you want.

```css
#grid-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#grid-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 8px;
}

#grid-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @cmprogram. I suppose I'm just interested in what `justify-content: stretch` can do (that `justify-content: start` can't)